# testing Internet Explorer 9 on virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I've downloaded the Windows 7 `.vhd` from Microsoft's site. I created a virtual PC from that `.vhd`. It runs OK, but the welcome screen want a password for one of the accounts (admin and administrator).

I've tried guessing a few passwords but with no luck...

Anyone knows the correct password?

Comment: Have you tried no password?  I would simply create my own virtual machine.

Comment: Also the username is almost certainly only administrator, not admin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't say where you downloaded this image but I guess you downloaded it from Microsofts [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en). If you scroll down on that page you can read this line

> The password to login to all of these images is Password1 and the username will be present when you first login

Comment: 1. That line is no longer there. 2. The password is **Password1** or **Passw0rd!** ?

Answer (score 21):

Note the new password might be

> Login Instructions
>   Login Information (for Windows Vista, 7, 8 VMs): 
>   IEUser, Passw0rd!

If you downloaded from http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads
see https://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/virtualmachine_instructions_2013-07-22.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Here it is: Passw0rd!
As the following image shows:

[image]

Comment: why the down vote? lol...

Comment: maybe because it's not soo good to get the PW, when you are already looged in. Then again, the PW is in the hint too...

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot figure out a password on a machine you should have access to, you can use a tool (NT Password) found at [this](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html) website to reset it. Just mount the ISO image to the virtual machine and have the virtual machine boot to it. It is a very easy command line tool. Enter will get you through most questions as it answers with the default answer.